# Want to create a Notification in Oreo without giving categories to channel item

Tags: android, notifications, categories, channel

How I can implement this kind of notification stuff in android Oreo without having channel categories has shown in picture 
[image]

Comment: U forgot to attach the picture?

Comment: now I have added how can I do this

Comment: If you are using targetSdkVersion less than 26, there is no need to implement notification channels